# Arrows between subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I decided to play around with [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/boxplot_vs_violin.html) example code a bit. I was able to figure out how to draw a straight line between the two subplots, even when the line is outside the bounds of one of the subplots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
axs = [ax1, ax2]

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

# generate some random test data
all_data = [np.random.normal(0, std, 100) for std in range(6, 10)]

# plot violin plot
axs[0].violinplot(all_data,
                  showmeans=False,
                  showmedians=True)
axs[0].set_title('Violin plot')

# plot box plot
axs[1].boxplot(all_data)
axs[1].set_title('Box plot')

# adding horizontal grid lines
for ax in axs:
    ax.yaxis.grid(True)
    ax.set_xticks([y + 1 for y in range(len(all_data))])
    ax.set_xlabel('Four separate samples')
    ax.set_ylabel('Observed values')

for tick in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tick.label.set_fontsize(20)
plt.setp(axs[0], xticklabels=['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'])

transFigure = fig.transFigure.inverted()
coord1 = transFigure.transform(ax1.transData.transform([5,10]))
coord2 = transFigure.transform(ax2.transData.transform([2,-10]))
line = mpl.lines.Line2D((coord1[0],coord2[0]),(coord1[1],coord2[1]),
                        c='k', lw=5, transform=fig.transFigure)
fig.lines.append(line)
```

Yes that added line is ugly but I just wanted to get it functional.

However, what I'd really like to do is make an arrow between the subplots, and I can't figure out how without jury-rigging my own arrow tails. Is there a way to do this that uses the `matplotlib.pyplot.arrow` class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also wanted to draw an arrow between two subplots but I didn't even know where to start! However, the line between subplots example in the original question gave me enough of a clue to get started...

First, I reduced the code in the original question to a minimal working example:

```
from matplotlib import lines, pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

# First subplot
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])

# Second subplot
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])

# Add line from one subplot to the other
xyA = [0.5, 1.0]
ax1.plot(*xyA, "o")
xyB = [0.75, 0.25]
ax2.plot(*xyB, "o")
transFigure = fig.transFigure.inverted()
coord1 = transFigure.transform(ax1.transData.transform(xyA))
coord2 = transFigure.transform(ax2.transData.transform(xyB))
line = lines.Line2D(
    (coord1[0], coord2[0]),  # xdata
    (coord1[1], coord2[1]),  # ydata
    transform=fig.transFigure,
    color="black",
)
fig.lines.append(line)

# Show figure
plt.show()
```

This produces the following output:

[image: Line between subplots]

Then, using [this blog post](https://www.cilyan.org/blog/2016/01/23/matplotlib-draw-between-subplots/), I *thought* the answer was to create a `matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch` and append it to `fig.patches` (instead of creating a `matplotlib.lines.Line2D` and appending it to `fig.lines`). After consulting the [`matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch.html?highlight=fancyarrowpatch), plus some trial and error, I came up with something that works *in matplotlib 3.1.2*:

```
from matplotlib import patches, pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

# First subplot
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])

# Second subplot
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])

# Add line from one subplot to the other
xyA = [0.5, 1.0]
ax1.plot(*xyA, "o")
xyB = [0.75, 0.25]
ax2.plot(*xyB, "o")
transFigure = fig.transFigure.inverted()
coord1 = transFigure.transform(ax1.transData.transform(xyA))
coord2 = transFigure.transform(ax2.transData.transform(xyB))
arrow = patches.FancyArrowPatch(
    coord1,  # posA
    coord2,  # posB
    shrinkA=0,  # so tail is exactly on posA (default shrink is 2)
    shrinkB=0,  # so head is exactly on posB (default shrink is 2)
    transform=fig.transFigure,
    color="black",
    arrowstyle="-|>",  # "normal" arrow
    mutation_scale=30,  # controls arrow head size
    linewidth=3,
)
fig.patches.append(arrow)

# Show figure
plt.show()
```

However, as per the comments below, this does not work in `matplotlib 3.4.2`, where you get this:

[image: Arrow between subplots - incorrect]

Notice that the ends of the arrow do not line up with the target points (orange circles), which they should do.

This `matplotlib` version change also causes the original line example to fail in the same way.

However, there is a better patch! Use `ConnectionPatch` ([docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.ConnectionPatch.html)), which is a subclass of `FancyArrowPatch`, instead of using `FancyArrowPatch` directly as the `ConnectionPatch` is designed specifically for this use case and deals with the transform more correctly, as shown in this [`matplotlib` documentation example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/userdemo/connect_simple01.html):

```
fig = plt.figure()

# First subplot
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1]) 

# Second subplot
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1]) 

# Add line from one subplot to the other
xyA = [0.5, 1.0]
ax1.plot(*xyA, "o")
xyB = [0.75, 0.25]
ax2.plot(*xyB, "o")
# ConnectionPatch handles the transform internally so no need to get fig.transFigure
arrow = patches.ConnectionPatch(
    xyA,
    xyB,
    coordsA=ax1.transData,
    coordsB=ax2.transData,
    # Default shrink parameter is 0 so can be omitted
    color="black",
    arrowstyle="-|>",  # "normal" arrow
    mutation_scale=30,  # controls arrow head size
    linewidth=3,
)
fig.patches.append(arrow)

# Show figure
plt.show()
```

This produces the correct output in both `matplotlib 3.1.2` and `matplotlib 3.4.2`, which looks like this:

[image]

To draw a correctly positioned line connecting across two subplots in `matplotlib 3.4.2`, use a `ConnectionPatch` as above but with `arrowstyle="-"` (i.e. no arrow heads, so just a line).

NB: You cannot use:

- `plt.arrow` as it is automatically added to the current axes so only appears in one subplot
- `matplotlib.patches.Arrow` as the axes-figure transform skews the arrow-head
- `matplotlib.patches.FancyArrow` as this also results in a skewed arrow-head

Comment: It's close, but for me, the head and tail of the arrow are just a little higher than what I set them with `coord1` and `coord2`. Any way to get those y-coordinates exact?

Comment: Yes. Use the `matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch` parameters `shrinkA=0` (tail) and `shrinkB=0` (head). The default is 2 for some reason. Answer edited accordingly.

Comment: The "shrink" parameters don't seem to do anything for me. I wonder if it is has to do with my graphics backend, Gt5. I tried changing this to Automatic, but that had no effect.

To be clear, it is only y1 (at the tail), and not x1, x2, or y2 of the arrow that is too high.

Comment: Is that on your own example with the violin plots or the minimal working example I posted? Can you mark the expected point to see how far out it is (e.g. `start = [0.5, 1.0]; ax1.plot(*start, marker="x"); end = [0.75, 0.25]; ax2.plot(*end, marker="x"); coord1 = transFigure.transform(ax1.transData.transform(start)); coord2 = transFigure.transform(ax2.transData.transform(end))`) and upload an image of the output?

Comment: I just ran it. Not sure how to upload a pic here in the comments, but the "x" markers are right where they are supposed to be at (0.5, 1) and (0.75, 0.25). I tried using every available backend in Spyder, restarting the console each time after changing the backend. The arrows are still not showing at the correct coordinates.

Comment: Ah, I see it now! There is something dodgy going on in matplotlib. With python 3.8.5 and matplotlib 3.1.2 the image is correct as above. But with matplotlib 3.4.2 the arrow position is wrong. However, there is a better patch! Use ConnectionPatch (docs: https://v.ht/A2V3), which is a subclass of FancyArrowPatch, instead of using FancyArrowPatch directly as the ConnectionPatch is designed specifically for this use case and deals with the transform more correctly (example: https://v.ht/ZMTh). I will update the answer accordingly after posting this comment.